# Reading an XML Element using LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I am trying to read a value from an XML file using LINQ.
This is really the first time that I am trying to use LINQ vs. the ordinary C#/.Net approach.

My XML looks like this:

```
<Description>
<Account Green="A" White="D">House</Account>
<Account Green="B" White="D">Car</Account>
</Description>
```

This is the LINQexpression I am using. I'd like to read the value House, in other words, the element with the attribute A and D.

```
var feeds = (from item in doc.Descendants("Description")
 from category in item.Elements("Account")                    
 let attribute = category.Attribute("Green")                    
 let xAttribute = category.Attribute("White")                    
 where attribute != null && (xAttribute != null && (xAttribute.Value == "A" 
 && attribute.Value == "D")) select item.Value).ToString();
```

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is it XmlElement or XElement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an `IEnumerable<string>` here - you apparently just want a single string here so add a `First()` to get the value of the first item in your enumeration:

```
var feeds = (from item in doc.Descendants("Description")
 from category in item.Elements("Account")                    
 let attribute = category.Attribute("Green")                    
 let xAttribute = category.Attribute("White")                    
 where attribute != null && (xAttribute != null && (xAttribute.Value == "A" 
 && attribute.Value == "D")) select category.Value).First();
```

An easier way to achieve the same might be:

```
string result = doc.Descendants("Account")
                   .Where(x => x.Attribute("Green") != null && x.Attribute("Green").Value == "A"
                            && x.Attribute("White") != null && x.Attribute("White").Value == "D")
                   .Select(x => x.Value)
                   .First();
```

Comment: But this gives me GreenWhite. Just as before.

Comment: @user1017102: Fixed - need to select `category.Value` and not `item.Value`